# How can I get portion of ordered data but avoid sorting again and again over requests?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, web-applications

I have a result set that it is too big to be displayed in one page. So I decided to show it in pages. Ok so far.
Now I need the results to displayed sorted. So the query would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE  
WHERE CONDITIONS  
ORDER BY COL  
LIMIT OFFSET, SIZE;
```

Now this will order and *then* give the portion I will display as page (I am right about first order and then apply `limit`, correct)?

But if I do this, for each page request, the results will be ordered again and again, right?
So this is bad. Is there a standard solution for this?
I assume an index on `COL` would be an improvement but I was wondering if there is a standard best practice.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the standard way is to use an index. I would definitely add an index to the column `col` and then make it part of the condition. When you have an index it won't sort over and over again because the index is already sorted.

Comment: Makes sense.I was wondering if there is something like caching on sql for the sorted data for example

Comment: I already thought that was the intend of your question. MySQL has something called a server sided cursor that buffers the result set: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursor-restrictions.html which might be a good way to do it. Though this I would not consider so much a "standard way" anymore but already a special way to do it. The advantage of buffering is no troubles with changing data on page forward and backwards but the disadvantage is if the data changes very fast the user still sees the old result set.